# Do something up to N times or until condition is met in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have some Scala code that should query a network service for a certain token, then compare that token to an expected one. I want to keep querying for the expected token until I find it, or until I've made N unsuccessful attempts.

Here's how it could be done in a Java-tacular fashion:

```
def keepLooking(expectedToken: String, maxTries: Int) {
  var tries = 0
  var token = ""
  do {
    Thread.sleep(tries * 1000) // don't overwhelm the service by calling it too fast!

    token = makeSomeNetworkCall()
    tries += 1
  } while (tries <= maxTries && token != expectedToken)
}
```

I'd like to do it more functionally. I have one idea:

```
1.to(maxTries) map { tryNum =>
  Thread.sleep(tryNum - 1 * 1000) // don't overwhelm the service by calling it too fast!
  makeSomeNetworkCall()
} exists (_ == expectedToken)
```

But this raises two questions:

1. `map` is lazy, so `exists` should short circuit it, right? I don't want to make 10 network calls if I find my token on the second call.
2. Is there a more idiomatic way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to 1.:

`map` is only lazy if you convert the `Range` to a `Stream`:

```
(1 to 10).toStream map (i => { println(i); i }) exists (_ == 2)
// will print
// 1
// 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Whether `map` is lazy, in general, depends on the collection type. To be sure it will be lazy, you could use `.toStream` or `.view` (the latter doesn't cache its results, so I usually opt for that).

Other than that, it seems OK to me, but it won't work for the case where you actually need to get some data from the response (I know that isn't what you need in this question, but I'm trying to think more generally here).

Answer (score 1):

`map` on a `Range` is not lazy, so it will make `maxTries` network calls and then look for `expectedToken` in the results. Instead, you can use some lazy structure. An `Iterator`, for example:

```
Iterator.fill(maxTries) {
  makeSomeNetworkCall()
}.exists(_ == expectedToken)
```

Comment: An `Iterator` is not functional, but then of course neither is directly doing I/O... if you talk to the scalaz people they will suggest using the I/O monad, a la Haskell, but I think they are in the minority in the Scala community.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 2, you can create your own `Stream`.

```
scala>  val keepLooking: Stream[Tuple2[Int, String]] = (0, "a") #:: (1, "aa") #:: keepLooking.tail.map { n => (n._1 + 1, n._2 + "a")}
keepLooking: Stream[(Int, String)] = Stream((0,a), ?)

scala> keepLooking.take(20).find(_._2 == "aaa")
res0: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((2,aaa))

scala> keepLooking.take(20).find(_._2 == "xxx")
res1: Option[(Int, String)] = None
```

This is a simplified example. In your case, you would replace `"a"`, `"aa"`, and `n._2 + "a"` with `makeSomeNetworkCall()` which I assume returns the `token` as a `String`. Then you can lazily take `maxTries` with `take(n)` and use `find` to see if the `expectedToken` exists.