# Accumulate result until some condition is met in functional way

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have some expensive computation in a loop, and I need to find max value produced by the calculations, though if, say, it will equal to LIMIT I'd like to stop the calculation and return my accumulator.

It may easily be done by recursion:

```
val list: List[Int] = ???
val UpperBound = ???

def findMax(ls: List[Int], max: Int): Int = ls match {
  case h :: rest =>
    val v = expensiveComputation(h)
    if (v == UpperBound) v
    else findMax(rest, math.max(max, v))

  case _ => max
}

findMax(list, 0)
```

My question: whether this behaviour template has a name and reflected in scala collection library?

Update: [Do something up to N times or until condition is met in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19847360/do-something-up-to-n-times-or-until-condition-is-met-in-scala) - There is an interesting idea (using laziness and find or exists at the end) but it is not directly applicable to my particular case or requires mutable var to track accumulator.

Comment: If performance is a very high priority, consider `if (v == UpperBound) return v`.  This non-local return is implemented by throwing an exception, and is probably measurably faster if you can't `@tailrec` and the list is long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your recursive function is quite nice, so honestly I wouldn't change that, but here's a way to use the collections library:

```
list.foldLeft(0) {
  case (max, next) =>
    if(max == UpperBound)
      max
    else
      math.max(expensiveComputation(next), max)
}
```

It will iterate over the whole list, but after it has hit the upper bound it won't perform the expensive computation.

### Update

Based on your comment I tried adapting foldLeft a bit, based on `LinearSeqOptimized`'s foldLeft implementation.

```
def foldLeftWithExit[A, B](list: Seq[A])(z: B)(exit: B => Boolean)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
  var acc = z
  var remaining = list
  while (!remaining.isEmpty && !exit(acc)) {
    acc = f(acc, list.head)
    remaining = remaining.tail
  }
  acc
}
```

Calling it:

```
foldLeftWithExit(list)(0)(UpperBound==){
  case (max, next) =>  math.max(expensiveComputation(next), max)
}
```

You could potentially use implicits to omit the first parameter of `list`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hm, reasonable, and quite good, indeed - traversing a collection without a computation is light (if it is not huge, of course, then better to stop early). Recursion is nice but I found that I need three variations for this - min, max and max with some more data attached. When I tried to find a generic variant which will allow more flexibility I found quite a number of problems which made idea infeasible (at least for me).

Comment: Updated my answer with a foldLeft that exits and doesn't iterate through the whole list. See if it helps.